# SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 11-19: truncated \UXXXXXXXX escape

Tags: python, csv, unicode, syntax-error

Im trying to run my coding after finished the whole coding while I run there is a problem in running the program.

This is the error:
Cell In[11], line 82
"]+", flags=re.UNICODE)
^
SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 11-19: truncated \UXXXXXXXX escape

and my coding:

```
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sb
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import re
import nltk
nltk.download('stopwords')
import gensim
 
#importing Dataset
df = pd.read_csv('tweet.csv')
 
#Creating the heatmap
plt.figure(figsize = (8,6))
sb.heatmap(df.isnull(), cbar=False , cmap = 'magma')

#convert all tweet into lowercase
df['tweet'] = df['text'].apply(str.lower)
df['tweet'].head()

#This function takes the full tweet text and removes twitter handles
def remove_username(tweet):
    remove_username = re.compile(r"@[A-Za-z0-9]+")
    return remove_username.sub(r"", tweet)

df['tweet'] = df['tweet'].apply(remove_username)
df['tweet'].head()

def remove_links(tweet):
    tweet_no_link = re.sub(r"http\S+", "", tweet)
    return tweet_no_link

df['tweet'] = df['tweet'].apply(remove_links)
df['tweet'].head()

#Remove punctuations
df['tweet'] = df['tweet'].str.replace("[^a-zA-Z#]", "")
df['tweet'].head()

#Remove Short Words
df['tweet'] = df['tweet'].apply(lambda x: ' '.join([w for w in x.split() if len(w)>3]))
df['tweet'].head()

#Remove Hashtag
def remove_hashtags(tweet, pattern):
    r = re.findall(pattern,tweet)
    for i in r:
        tweet = re.sub(i,'', tweet)
    return tweet

df['tweet'] = np. vectorize(remove_hashtags)(df['tweet'], "#[\w]")

#Prepare Stop Words
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
stop_words = stopwords.words('english')
stop_words.extend(['from', 'https', 'twitter', 'still'])
from gensim import corpora
from gensim import models

def remove_stopwords(tweet):
    return[[word for word in gensim.utils.simple_preprocess(tweet) if word not in stop_words] for tweet in tweet]
df['tweet'] = remove_stopwords(df['tweet'])
df['tweet'].head()

def remove_emojis(tweet):
    remove_emojis = re.compile("["
        u"\U00002700-\U000027BF"  # Dingbats
        u"\U0001F600-\U0001F64F"  # Emoticons
        u"\U00002600-\U000026FF"  # Miscellaneous Symbols
        u"\U0001F300-\U0001F5FF"  # symbols & pictographs
        u"\U0001F680-\U0001F6FF"  # Transport & Map Symbols
        u"\U0001F1E0-\U0001F1FF"  # FLAGS (IOS)
        u"\U00002500-\U00002BEF"  # chinese char
        u"\U00002702-\U00027B0"
        u"\U000024C2-\U0001F251"
        u"\U0001f926-\U000f937"
        u"\U00010000-\U0010ffff"
        u"\u2640-\u2642"
        u"\u2600-\u2B55"
        u"\u200d"
        u"\u23cf"
        u"\u23e9"
        u"\u231a"
        u"\ufe0f" # dingbats
        u"\u3030"
                      "]+", flags=re.UNICODE)
    return remove_emojis.sub(r'', string)

df['tweet'] = df['tweet'].apply(remove_emojis)
df['tweet'].head()
```

I saw the other solution that need to put r in the line that we have problem but for my case my line either in between this:

```
df = pd.read_csv('tweet.csv')
 
#Creating the heatmap
plt.figure(figsize = (8,6))
sb.heatmap(df.isnull(), cbar=False , cmap = 'magma')

#convert all tweet into lowercase
df['tweet'] = df['text'].apply(str.lower)
df['tweet'].head()

#This function takes the full tweet text and removes twitter handles
def remove_username(tweet):
```

so im confused where do i need to put the r.

Comment: You are using `u""` strings. Are you on Python 2?

Comment: What might be the reason for the error: you have two bad unicode escapes in your emoji regex, they are one character short.

Comment: @KlausD. is exactly right.  If I fix the two truncated codes (00027B0 and 000f937), the code works.  Notice that the second one needs to be 0001f937.

Comment: I use python3 and already change it according you stated. Thanks a lot...